# AWS lambda function to restart one of the ECS cluster service

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

We are deploying multiple service in **ECS cluster** with **fargate**, On the front end we are using **nginx service**. On the backend some services are getting deployed frequently. Once any of the backend service deployed we manually need to update nginx service forcefully. Do we have any approach to update only nginx service forcefully when any of the new service deployed successfully?

How we can achieve this ? using lambda or cloudwatch....
Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: `update_service`? See [this][https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.update_service]. You can do it with foreceNewDeployment, I think.

Comment: By manually we are able to for force update_service...but we need to do as a automation way.....like if any services deployed under the cluster we want to restart one container each time

Comment: Can you run a `update_service` using CLI? if so, you could do that from within a backend Docker image (e.g. in a startup.sh script referencing the nginx service). If not, there's a CloudWatch event triggered if a task is started [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#ecs-event-types) and then use a Lambda function to run the `update_service` as [done here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwet.html)

Answer (score 0):

When the backend Services are updated you can use cloud watch to trigger a lambda. This lambda can use the AWS SDK to to restart the Nginx container service/task. You could also version your Nginx container along with all your backend services so that that the a new Nginx image is push up when your backend changes and the task definition is changed contains the new image. Providing your using AWS ECS Service it can update it self.

See here for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service.html

Comment: Achieved this with lambda function....added step in code pipeline with json payload. When deployment task finish it will trigger lambda function to stop and start the nginx service.